# How to join multiple variable declarations with Resharper?

Tags: resharper

If I have

```
class A
{
   int a;
   int b;
}
```

Is there a way for resharper to reformat this code on *"code cleanup"* action to the following?

```
class A
{
   int a, b;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do it in ReSharper because this is considered a bad style. See [Why do you not declare several variables of the same type on the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100633/why-do-you-not-declare-several-variables-of-the-same-type-on-the-same-line) and [Declaring Multiple Variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694102/declaring-multiple-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: I totally agree with you, this is why Resharper offers a refactoring option to split into separate declarations, however, is it possible to give it an inspection severity?

Comment: @PiersMyers I've filed a feature request for it http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-362348 . Feel free to vote for it.

Comment: @DmitryOsinovskiy This is what I expected. I disagree with this style guideline, however. I disagree even stronger with the idea of enforcing a stylistic choice.

Comment: @Gleno What do you mean with "enforcing"? Currently there is no highlighting for this, and even if there would be one, you would be able to turn it off.

Comment: @DmitryOsinovskiy Perhaps I misspoke. My meaning is that since there's an option to split, there should too be an option to join - for those of us who don't agree with the stylistic choice you subscribe to. Thanks for taking your time to answer my question though. I'm a big fan of R#. ;)