# How do I declare two or more data types on the same line??(New to programming)

Tags: java, string, class, types, double

I am having difficulty combining two data types on the same line for simplicity purposes... Here is my current code:

```
public class countryPopulations{

    static String zero = "Canada ";
    static String one = "USA ";
    static String two = "China ";

    static double Canada = 35.16;
    static double US = 316.1;
    static double China = 1.357;

    static String million = " million";
    static String billion = " billion";


    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println(zero +Canada + million);
        System.out.println(one +US + million);
        System.out.println(two +China + billion);

    }

}
```

As you can see this is a lot of work just to print "Canada 35.16 million" on one line, or "US 316.1 million". I hope I have included enough information and if anyone could help that would be great! Also if you have any additional information that you could share or tips about the code I have just presented (as I am clearly a beginner at programming) that would be awesome.. Thanks again!

Comment: Look t the format method on String - which is probably in the tutorial you are using

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117500/java-one-line-variable-declaration and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100633/why-do-you-not-declare-several-variables-of-the-same-type-on-the-same-line

Comment: Unless you are going to perform math operations on those doubles, then you could simply do `static String canada = "Canada 35.16 million"` etc for US and China

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to use array(s), and something like

```
String[] countries = { "Canada", "USA", "China" };
double[] population = { 35.16, 316.1, 1.357 };
String[] suffix = { "million", "billion" };
for (int i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%s %.3f %s%n", countries[i], population[i],
            (i == 2) ? suffix[1] : suffix[0]);
}
```

Or, you could use a `Country` POJO like

```
static class Country {
    String name;
    double population;
    boolean billion = false;

    public Country(String name, double population, boolean billion) {
        this.name = name;
        this.population = population;
        this.billion = billion;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s %.3f %s", name, population,
                (billion) ? "billion" : "million");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Country [] countries = new Country[] {
            new Country("Canada",35.16,false),
            new Country("USA",316.1,false),
            new Country("China",1.357, true)
    };
    for (Country c : countries) {
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Elliott Frisch, what is a POJO?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is not combining two data types.
As in this case
System.out.println(zero +Canada + million);
Since your first argument to System.out.println is zero  which is string.
What java will do is to convert following arguments to string or
if they are objects it will call toString method in the Object class.