# Which is the more proper way to declare Buttons ect... in Java

Tags: java

I can't seem to find a direct answer, and it seems I've seen it done mulitple ways, here and else where. Is there even a better way to define that I have not seen?
Which is the more proper way to define:

```
    Button image1;
Button image2;
Button image3;
Button image4;
Button image5;
Button image6;
Button image7;
```

Or

```
  Button  image1,image2,image3,image4,image5,image6,
  image7;
```

Comment: I prefer each variable to be declared separately. This results in more readable code and the purpose of each variable can be separately documented. Also, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100633/why-do-you-not-declare-several-variables-of-the-same-type-on-the-same-line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that your button variable names end in numbers that are monotonically increasing, it suggests that you're creating a collection of like buttons with similar function, and if so, it seems like "none of the above" may be the best answer. Consider creating a collection of buttons:

```
private List<Button> imageButtons = new ArrayList<>();
```

And then creating and adding the buttons you need.

Comment: Thanks for my first up-vote!!

Comment: I like this method, though I do have other buttons with other names in the activity as well. These are part of a gallery with an image set as the background of a button, once clicked it opens an expanded image view of the image and gives the user other options. The buttons are basically thumbnails of nature photographs. Would <array> work with unique button names? Such as Button Cat; Button dog; ect... ect?

Comment: @Oliver: you can use a `HashMap<String, name>` if you want a collection that ties a name String to a button, or you could create a wrapper class to hold the Button, its name, etc.  Also Luke's answer looks good... 1+ to it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "proper way". The way you define your variables depends on a few factors - the main being javadoc. In your first example, you can give each variable its own javadoc, while in the second, all the buttons would share a javadoc comment. For example:

```
/**
 * I am button a.
 */
Button a;

/**
 * I am button b.
 */
Button b;

/**
 * I am button c.
 */
Button c;
```

Each button above has its own javadoc comment.

```
/**
 * These are some buttons.
 */
Button a, b, c;
```

While in this example all of the variables above share a javadoc comment, so which method you use depends on what you want to do.

Although in the specific example you gave, @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter is correct, an array would work best for storing your buttons.

**For an unknown amount of buttons:**

`List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>();`

**For a known amount of buttons:**

- `Button[] buttons = new Button[]{new Button("A"), new Button("B")};`

or

- `Button[] buttons = new Button[numberOfButtons];`